# SQL Query group by and count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query and I would like to get the count of rows group by column.

```
  SELECT COL1, COL2
  FROM TABLE-A 
  GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

Here is the result set I am getting for the above query. Thank you for any suggestion.

```
Col1            Col2
-------------------
Atlanta         122
Atlanta         133
Atlanta         323
Boston          44
Boston          99
LA              3323
```

Here is the result set I need help with the query.

```
Col1            Col2
-------------------
Atlanta         3
Boston          2
LA              1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to use the aggregate function and dont group by the one you need to count, in this case col2

```
 SELECT COL1, count(COL2)
  FROM TABLE-A 
  GROUP BY COL1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COL1,COUNT(COL1) as Col2
FROM TABLE-A 
GROUP BY COL1
```